# How can i access ipv4 on ipv6 server having nat ip4 with blocked ipv4 access?

Tags: linux, nat, vps, ipv4

I have a nat vps, there are some restrictions set by hosting company because of many abuses, they provide nat ipv4 and dedicated ipv6 on a server, before the server was working normal like i can ping or download from webpages easily using ipv4, but due to users doing netscan they have restricted ipv4 access to the internet making many things not work. I am still able to use my nat ports to access my server, i found a way to get ipv4 access again on server by installing warp, but after installing it i am unable to access my server from ipv4 nat ports, but ipv6 access works fine. Dns64 or Nat64 is also not a solution working for me, i mean pretty worse ms i get by that. What could be the solution to this?

Comment: we do not help users to violence or remove restrictions from services. thats against the CoC and ToS. Or shortly said, imho off topic

Comment: It's not against Tos of host, we (normal users) are effected by that, so just trying to find solution to get ipv4 connectivity, like by using warp or something but not effect nat ports. If i use warp then i am unable to access server on ipv4 i.e using ipv4 ports.